# Huffman code for image compression - Java

Tags: encoding, decoding, huffman-code, image-compression

Since I started my Codification Theory course, I've started to feel curious about practical implementations of information theory algorithms. I've researched about Huffman code and how this is used for data compress. I am specially curious about building an image (JPG,  JPEG) compressor using Huffman codes but I'm struggling in the implementation.

My idea for this program goes like this:

**1**. Implement a HuffmanCode class, which is used to encode and decode a string input (Find the char frequency for all characters in string, build Huffman tree, generate Huffman code, etc.). I found this implementation "[here](https://blog.devgenius.io/the-compression-chronicles-huffman-encoding-ab063e28dfb1)".

**2**. Having the Huffman code implementation, I read an image input and convert it to a byte array. Then, I use this byte array to build a string having all of these bytes. Now, I apply the Huffman code for the previous string.

**3**. The result of the previous step is a binary string, then I convert this binary string to a byte array.

**4**. Finally, write the corresponding image to the previous byte array and output.

Following this reasoning, I got a **RasterFormatException : Data array too small (should be > 749999 )**. I've tried others implementations for writing the image but I am still getting some other Exceptions such as **image == null** exception.

I was wondering if someone has a better approach for building this program, or if I am missing something related to writing/reading images in Java (I'm new with this tools), or if I am misunderstanding something related to Huffman codes.

The HuffmanCode class is the following (I made some changes):

```
public class HuffmanCode {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String test = "AndersonAndresLlanosQuintero";
        System.out.println(countFrequency(test));
    }

    // Clase nodo para las construcción del árbol.
    class HuffmanNode{
        public int frecuencia;
        public char caracter;
        public HuffmanNode leftNode;
        public HuffmanNode rightNode;

        public HuffmanNode(){}

        public int getFrecuencia() {
            return frecuencia;
        }

        public void setFrecuencia(int frecuencia) {
            this.frecuencia = frecuencia;
        }

        public char getCaracter() {
            return caracter;
        }

        public void setCaracter(char caracter) {
            this.caracter = caracter;
        }

        public HuffmanNode getLeftNode() {
            return leftNode;
        }

        public void setLeftNode(HuffmanNode leftNode) {
            this.leftNode = leftNode;
        }

        public HuffmanNode getRightNode() {
            return rightNode;
        }

        public void setRightNode(HuffmanNode rightNode) {
            this.rightNode = rightNode;
        }
    }

    // Clase comparadora para saber cuando un nodo está por encima de otro.

    class HuffmanComparator implements Comparator<HuffmanNode> {
        public int compare(HuffmanNode x, HuffmanNode y) {
            return x.frecuencia - y.frecuencia;
        }
    }

    /* Procedemos a implementar el algoritmo : */

    /* Necesitaremos la raíz del árbol de Huffman y un Map para
    hacer match entre un símbol y su frecuencia de aparición.
     */

    private Map<Character,String> charToBinaryMap;
    private HuffmanNode root;
    private String nuevaSalida;

    public HuffmanNode getRoot(){
        return this.root;
    }
    public String getNuevaSalida(){
        return this.nuevaSalida;
    }
    public HuffmanCode(){
        this.root = null;
        this.charToBinaryMap = new HashMap<Character, String>();
    }

    public HuffmanNode getTree(){
        return this.root;
    }

    /* Teniendo el código de Huffman, decodificar simplemente asigna a cada arista
    * del árbol el símbolo de 0 o 1. Para esta implementación, las aristas a la izq.
    * tendrán el símbolo "0" y para la derecha el símbolo "1". */

    public String Decodificar(String binaryString, HuffmanNode root){
        HuffmanNode current = root;
        StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < binaryString.length(); i++){
            if(current != null){
                if((current.rightNode == null && binaryString.charAt(i) == '1') || (current.leftNode == null && binaryString.charAt(i) == '0')){
                    i--;
                    build.append(current.caracter);
                    current = root;
                    continue;
                }
                if(binaryString.charAt(i) == '1'){
                    current = current.rightNode;
                }else {
                    current = current.leftNode;
                }
            }
        }
        if(current != null){
            build.append(current.caracter);
        }
        return build.toString();
    }


    /*Codificar : Crear el árbol más óptimo para nuestra cadena de bits. */

    public String Codificar(String strToCode){

        Map<Character, Integer> charOcurrence = countFrequency(strToCode);

        int n = charOcurrence.size();

        /* Creamos una cola de prioridad con el mapeo de la ocurrencia de símbolos
        que organice los símbolos de acuerdo al comparador de Huffman. */

        PriorityQueue<HuffmanNode> huffmanHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(n, new HuffmanComparator());

        // Recorremos el HashMap y creamos la cola de prioridad de acuerdo a la frecuencia del símbolo:

        charOcurrence.forEach((key, value) -> {
            HuffmanNode node = new HuffmanNode();
            node.caracter = key;
            node.frecuencia = value;
            node.leftNode = null;
            node.rightNode = null;

            huffmanHeap.add(node);
        });

        /* Transformamos la cola prioritaria (minHeap) en un árbol de Huffman mediante
        el algoritmo visto en clase. */

        while(huffmanHeap.size() > 1){

            HuffmanNode leaf1 = huffmanHeap.peek();
            huffmanHeap.poll();
            HuffmanNode leaf2 = huffmanHeap.peek();
            huffmanHeap.poll();

            HuffmanNode ptr = new HuffmanNode();

            ptr.frecuencia = leaf1.frecuencia + leaf2.frecuencia;
            ptr.caracter = '-';
            ptr.leftNode = leaf1;
            ptr.rightNode = leaf2;
            huffmanHeap.add(ptr);

        }

        this.root = huffmanHeap.peek();

        /* Teniendo el árbol de Huffman, buscamos las palabras código
         y mostramos al usuario como se han codificado los símbolos : */

        System.out.println(" Caracter | Palabra Código | Frecuencia");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        codeWords(root, "");

        /* Codificamos el input con las nuevas palabras código obtenidas : */

        StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
        for(Character ch : strToCode.toCharArray()){
            build.append(this.charToBinaryMap.get(ch));
        }

        this.nuevaSalida = build.toString();

        int pesoOriginal = strToCode.getBytes().length*8;
        int pesoComprimido = nuevaSalida.length();

        System.out.println("Peso original (bits) :" + pesoOriginal);
        /*System.out.println("Codificación de Huffman: " + nuevaSalida);
         */
        System.out.println("Longitud de la codificación de Huffman: " + nuevaSalida.length());
        System.out.println("Peso post-codificación: " + pesoComprimido);

        return nuevaSalida;
    }

    /* countFrequency : Cuenta número de ocurrencias de un caracter. */

    public static Map<Character, Integer> countFrequency(String input){
        HashMap<Character, Integer> mapFrequency = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
            if(!mapFrequency.containsKey(input.toCharArray()[i])){
                mapFrequency.put(input.toCharArray()[i], 1);
            }else{
                mapFrequency.put(input.toCharArray()[i], mapFrequency.get(input.toCharArray()[i])+1);
            }
        }
        return mapFrequency;
    }

    /* Como queremos las hojas del árbol de Huffman, hacemos un simple
    * recorrido in-order sobre el árbol, imprimiendo únicamente las hojas. */

    public void codeWords(HuffmanNode root, String str){
        if(root.leftNode != null){
            codeWords(root.leftNode, str + 0);
        }
        if(root.leftNode == null && root.rightNode == null){
            this.charToBinaryMap.put(root.caracter, str);
            System.out.println(root.caracter + "   |  " + str +  "  |  " + root.frecuencia);
            return;
        }
        if(root.rightNode != null){
            codeWords(root.rightNode, str + 1);
        }
    }

    public String charList(HuffmanNode root, String str){
        if(root.leftNode != null){
            charList(root.leftNode, str);
        }
        if(root.leftNode == null && root.rightNode == null){
            str = str + root.caracter;
        }
        if(root.rightNode != null){
            charList(root.rightNode, str);
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

The ImageProcessing class, where the whole reasoning is developed, is the following:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;
    import java.awt.image.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.math.BigInteger;
    import java.nio.charset.Charset;
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

    public class ImageProcessing {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        /* Convert image to byte array and then, to a string */

        StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/WorkSpace/HuffmanCompression/src/draken.jpg"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg", bos );
        byte [] data = bos.toByteArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            build.append(data[i]);
        }

        /* Use Huffman code to the previous string.*/

        HuffmanCode huffman = new HuffmanCode();
        String prueba = huffman.Codificar(build.toString());
        String pruebaDecodificada = huffman.Decodificar(prueba, huffman.getTree());
        String strToByte = huffman.getNuevaSalida();


        /*
        String inputString = strToByte;
        Charset dictionaryMap = StandardCharsets.UTF_16;
        byte[] newImage = inputString.getBytes(dictionaryMap);
        */

        /*Convert the binary string to a byte array and then, output the corresponding image. I copied and paste this part of the code from this blog. */

        byte[] bval = new BigInteger(strToByte, 2).toByteArray();
        OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("output.jpg");

        BufferedImage image = createRGBImage(bval, bImage.getWidth(), bImage.getHeight());
        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", stream);
        }
        finally {
            stream.close();
        }


    }

    public static BufferedImage createRGBImage(byte[] bytes, int width, int height) {
        DataBufferByte buffer = new DataBufferByte(bytes, bytes.length);
        ColorModel cm = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB), new int[]{8, 8, 8}, false, false, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
        return new BufferedImage(cm, Raster.createInterleavedRaster(buffer, width, height, width * 3, 3, new int[]{0, 1, 2}, null), false, null);
    }


}
```

I will be grateful if someone can help me, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Too much code here to go through -- my suggestion would be to first try out the compression/decompression on simple strings. Once that's working correctly you can move on to more complex applications of the algorithm.

Comment: By the way, even once you get this working, what you describe will not significantly compress any images, since you are missing the crucial part of JPEG, which are the discrete cosine transforms and quantization frequency components. Without some sort of modeling of the redundancy or unperceivable parts of the data, just Huffman coding won't get you hardly any compression.